# How to calculate the deepest node in WordNet using NLTK?

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

Is there built-in functionality to find the lowest word in a word hierarchy using NLTK? For example, if there were no edge between 'placenta' and 'carnivore' in the first graph at http://www.randomhacks.net/2009/12/29/visualizing-wordnet-relationships-as-graphs/, the lowest words would be 'placenta' and 'carnivore' (both having distance 10 from 'entity').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the synset with no hyponyms, e.g.

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

lowest_level = set()

for ss in wn.all_synsets():
    if ss.hyponyms() == []:
        lowest_level.add(ss)

len(lowest_level) # 97651
```

If you would like to exclude synsets with instance hyponyms:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn

lowest_level = set()

for ss in wn.all_synsets():
    if ss.hyponyms() == ss.instance_hyponyms() == []:
        lowest_level.add(ss)

len(lowest_level) # 97187
```

Comment: I read his question as also wanting the distance for each from "entity", and then listing just those with the longest distance.

Comment: Hmmm... Like http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html#nltk.corpus.reader.wordnet.Synset.shortest_path_distance ?

Comment: Yes, I suppose running that 97651 times, to get distance to "entity", would do it. I bet there is a more efficient way, though :-)